# Filtrar o que estou trazendo no NavLink

Tags: javascript, node.js, react

Estou importando o NavLink do react-router-dom e montando o meu menu assim:

```
<Nav navbar>{createLinks(routes)}</Nav>
```

No arquivo routes.js estou montando enviando conforme código abaixo:

```
var routes = [
  {
    path: "/index",
    name: "Dashboard",
    icon: "ni ni-tv-2 text-primary",
    component: Index,
    tipo: 1,
    layout: "/admin",
  },
  {
    path: "/solicitacoes-trabalho",
    name: "Solicitações",
    icon: "ni ni-cart text-orange",
    tipo: 1,
    component: Solicitacoes,
    layout: "/admin",
  },
  {
    path: "/Clientes",
    name: "Clientes",
    icon: "ni ni-single-02 text-orange",
    tipo: 2,
    component: Clientes,
    layout: "/admin",
  },
];

export default routes;
```

Há como na exibição eu conseguir filtrar pelo tipo e só mostrar o que for do tipo 1 ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Usar o metodo [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) pode resolver

`<Nav navbar>{createLinks(routes.filter(route => route.tipo === 1))}</Nav>`

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Muito bom Guilherme... isso mesmo, obrigado